# Log in two different files from apache server

Tags: php, apache, exec, error-logging, error-log

Can we have two different error_log files for our server? Because I want to have separate error_log file for a single file.

**Can i do this in apache server?**

I know that we can use the **exec**  for this purpose.

```
            exec("$phpBianryPath $logDir/call.php  >> $logDir/log_file_1.log 2>&1 &");
```

But problem with this is I am not able to response from this file to where it is called. And I want to return response from this file to where it is called.

My first priority is to do it without using exec but you can give suggestions for "how to return response from exec". Because If it's not possible to do without the use of exec then i will have to use exec.

Comment: Specify a reason for down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

You can, just set a separate CustomLog with a name, and specify a new log path.

i.e:

in your vhost / apache conf:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" another
CustomLog /path/to/another/logs/access_log another
```